# Unable to set the value of multidimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an static array property

```
private static $config = array(
    'base_url' => '',
    'environment' => '',
    'database' => array(
        'dbdriver' => '',
        'dbhost'   => '',
        'dbname'   => '',
        'dbuser'   => '',
        'dbpass'   => ''
    ),
    'default_controller' => ''
);
```

There is a static method to set the value of items by key

```
public static function set($key, $value)
{
    if(isset(self::$config[$key]))
        self::$config[$key] = $value;
    else
    {
        foreach (self::$config as $i => $j) 
        {
            if(!is_array($j))
                continue;
            foreach ($j as $k => $v)
            {
                if($k == $key)
                {
                    $j[$k] = $value;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works in case of base_url, environment etc. But when i am doing `Config::set('dbdriver', 'PDO')` it is not working. Also i am not sure how to handle it if the nested array goes more deep.

Please help me fixing this issue or i would welcome any good solution also.

Thanks

Comment: This question's answer looks like it would work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483496/how-to-dynamically-set-value-in-multidimensional-array-by-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you are inside the `foreach` you are given *copies* of the values.  `$j[$k] = $value;` doesn't update the main array, as you see.

You need to use *references* to make sure the original array gets updated.

```
// The `&` makes $j into a reference
foreach (self::$config as $i => &$j){
    if(!is_array($j)){
        continue;
    }

    // You don't actually need to use a `foreach` here
    // You can just check if the key is set
    if(isset($j[$key])){
        // This should update the main array
        $j[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Right i should call it as reference. But how about making this thing work for any level of array ?

Comment: Would you know what all the parent keys are, or just the child key?

Comment: I might not. This code of yours works well if there are only two level of arrays. I want it to find the key of any level of array and set its value